# AngularJS: What is the best way to bind a directive value to a service value changed via a controller?

Tags: angularjs, service, binding, directive

I want to create a "Header" service to handle the title, buttons, and color of it.
The main idea is to be able to customize this header with a single line in my controllers like this:

```
function HomeCtrl($scope, Header) {
    Header.config('Header title', 'red', {'left': 'backBtn', 'right': 'menuBtn'});
}
```

So I created a service (for now I'm only focussing on the title):

```
app.service('Header', function() {
    this.config = function(title, color, buttons) {
        this.title = title;
    }
});
```

...And a directive:

```
app.directive('header', ['Header', function(Header) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div class="header">{{title}}</div>',
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
            $scope.$watch(function() { return Header.title }, function() {
                $scope.title = Header.title;
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

So, this actually works but I'm wondering if there are no better way to do it.
Especially the $watch on the Header.title property. Doesn't seem really clean to me.

Any idea on how to optimize this ?

Edit: My header is not in my view. So I can't directly change the $scope value from my controller.

Edit2: Here is some of my markup

```
<div class="app-container">
    <header></header>

    <div class="content" ng-view></div>

    <footer></footer>
</div>
```

(Not sure this piece of html will help but I don't know which part would actually...)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution may be to just add to rootScope. I always do this with a few truly global variables that every controller will need, mainly user login data etc.

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.appData={
            "header" :  {"title" : "foo"}, 
            "user" :{}
    };
});
```

.. then inject $rootScope into your controllers as warranted.

Comment: Actually this is what I did before searching for a cleaner solution :) I'm not sure this is best practice (using the $rootScope). Also, I wanted to be able to configure my header in a single line in my controllers so I keep it short.

A dedicated service seemed like a good idea.

Comment: From the AngularJS FAQs:                                                   Occasionally there are pieces of data that you want to make global to the whole app. For these, you can inject $rootScope and set values on it like any other scope. Since the scopes inherit from the root scope, these values will be available to the expressions attached to directives like ng-show just like values on your local $scope.  http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq

Comment: And also from the Angular FAQs ... "Conversely, don't create a service whose only purpose in life is to store and return bits of data"

Comment: Damn, that's exactly what I'm doing (Using a service only to return bits of data)... So is there another solution if I don't want to have 3 or 4 $rootScope.myvar = myvalue in each one of my controllers ?

Comment: Possibly use eventing to message between your controllers? (Although I think your original approach with $rootScope was a good one) $rootScope.$broadcast("headerConfigRequest",{...}); and have your header Controller ... .$on("headerConfigRequest", function...)

Comment: Interesting. I'll try it. Thanks for you answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using title in your view, why use scope to hold the object, rather than the service? This way you would not need a directive to update scope.header, as the binding would update it if this object changes

```
   function HomeCtrl($scope, Header) {
     $scope.header = Header.config('Header title', 'red', {'left': 'backBtn', 'right': 'menuBtn'});
    }
```

and refer to title as

```
<h1>{{header.title}}</h1>
```

**Update**

Put this in a controller that encapsulates the  tags to bind to the header:

```
$scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function($currentRoute, $previousRoute) {
    //assume you can set this based on your $routeParams
    $scope.header = Header.config($routeParams);
});
```

Comment: Because the header is not in my ng-view.

Comment: It doesn't have to be.. could you post your markup as well?

Comment: Well it's a mobile application. The header and footer are out of my view so I don't need to "pollute" my templates with it. I guess this is less flexible but more DRY.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. I'll update my post with some markup.